# can not find the proof that logarithms are the inverse of exponentials

Tags: calculus

I have been taught by the most powerful magic of mathematics - Hand waving - that the logarithms are inverses of the exponential.  I have seen the graphs where each one is graph, showing they are reflective over the line $y=x$.  I do not doubt they are inverses of each other; however, when I learned about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculates, I saw a proof.  When I learned about the Mean Value Theorem, I saw a proof.  When is learned about Riemann sums, I saw a proof. When I learned about derivatives, I saw a proof.

Where is the proof that logarithms are the inverse of exponential.  I am just given a relationship $\log_b (a) = b^a$. Where's the proof?

I know there are many wise PHD here that can unleash the power of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, crush conjectures with the squeeze theorem, follow the pigeon hole principle, make portals between fields, and even transform me into a coffee cup.

What is the proof of $\log_b(a) = b^a$?

Comment: What's your definition of both? People usually define one of those to be the inverse of the other.

Comment: Of all the questions I've seen on Math.SE so far, this is easily among the most amusingly written.

Comment: @JavierBadia, That is about it.  Told the formula to use, and the rules of how to manipulate either one and shown a graph and told they are inverses.  Oh, and the natural log is also an integral.

Comment: @JavierBadia, your comment makes it seem like its arbitrary which one I define as the inverse of the other. That just seems strange to me.  That logic is : Left is the inverse of Right, and Right is the inverse of Left.  Just seems lacking, noting how well $\ln$ and $e$ fit together with all of their properties.

Comment: I love the way this post was written! More people need to write like this! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proof might interest you:

Suppose we define $e^x$ to be the function $f(x)$ satisfying $f'(x) = f(x)$ with $f(0) = 1$.  With implicit differentiation, we note that
$$
f(f^{-1}(x)) = x \implies f'(f^{-1}(x))(f^{-1})'(x) = 1
$$ 
Rearranging yields
$$
(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))} = \frac{1}{f(f^{-1}(x))} = \frac 1x
$$
Now, define $f^{-1}$ to be this inverse of $f$.  We deduce from the above that $f^{-1}$ has derivative $\frac 1x$.  We note that since $f(0) = 1$, $f^{-1}(1) = 0$. $f^{-1}$, that is, $\ln x$, is the unique function satisfying the conditions $(f^{-1})'(x) = 1/x$ and $f^{-1}(0) = 1$. Thus, $f^{-1}$ must have all the properties of $\ln x$

We could go through the same process in reverse.  The point is, once you know that $e^x$ has one of its defining properties, you may conclude that its inverse has all of the defining properties of $\ln x$. Similarly, once you know that $\ln x$ has one of its defining properties, you may conclude that its inverse has all of the defining properties of $e^x$.

I hope you find this satisfactory.

Comment: That is a clever proof.  So, that shows the algebraic structure between both the logarithms and exponential? Also, the other variations(limits, integral, etc) is the inverse mapping still exist?

Comment: I suppose you could say this "shows the algebraic structure". I would say it shows you how, given one definition, you may deduce all definitions of the inverse. Any of the "other variations" defining $e^x$ or $\ln x$ can be shown to be equivalent to the differential properties used for this proof, so you could always use this proof as an intermediary. However, off the top of my head, I can think of no direct line of proof (i.e. one that does not at some point invoke differentiation) from the limit definition of one to the limit definition of its inverse.

Comment: It's interesting to see how this proof works in reverse.  That is, let $f$ be the function whose derivative is $1/x$ and which satisfies $f(1) = 0$ (clearly equivalent to the integral definition).  Show that its inverse must satisfy the defining properties of $e^x$.  You may find that the necessary rearrangement is surprisingly different.

Comment: I like your answer the best.  I am going to study more about algebraic structure.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since exponential functions are 1-1 (pass the horizontal line test), and they are continuous, they must have an inverse function. The inverse is called the "logarithm". That's it! No proof needed. It is just definition. Their existence is guaranteed.

If you are trying to get your head around the "funny" way the logarithm is written, this might help.

Instead of writing $y = a^x$, write $y = exp_{a}(x)$; then $x = log_{a}(y)$. That's it. Just interchange $x$ and $y$ as you have been taught to do with other functions.

Comment: Then how is $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(x^{1/n}-1\right)$  an inverse of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$.  How can that be?

Comment: @yiyi you should have specified that this is the definition you were starting from.  The logarithm and exponential functions are "defined" differently by different authors and in different situations, but these many definitions may be shown to be equivalent.  Your question, it seems, is whether these functions defined by limits can be shown to be inverses, directly.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, My issue is that I have been told several forms for each, and I know they are inverses, yet nobody gave a proof, so I thought if I knew the proof, it would unify all the different forms together.  $\ln x = \int_1^x (1/t)dt$ the limit forms, series form, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = y = c^x$ be a exponential function, such $c>0$ and $c\neq 1$.

Take logarithms from both sides with base $c$. Then we have:

$$log_cy = log_cc^x = x$$

In other word:

$$f^{-1}(y) = g(y) = x = log_cy$$

Which means that the inverse of an exponential function is logatimic function. Also you can do the other way around by you just need to use the LHS and RHS as exponents and use $c$ as base.

Comment: Now, how does one use that magic upon the limit definitions of both of those functions?